# Does this type of equation for an airfoil exist?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In a common airfoil, such as a plane's wing, diminished pressure over the top of the wing and increased pressure under the wing, generally speaking, will cause the wing to lift. Now, a man standing under a speeding aircraft should feel the wing's bottom pressure as the wing passes over his head. Conversely, if he is above the wing as it passes, he should sense the diminished pressure of the top of the wing. But in both cases, only up to a certain distance. If the distance between the man and the wing is too great, he will no longer feel the effects of the passing wing.  My question: Is there an equation that, when fed all the variables, will give the theoretical distance above and below the wing where the man, or a sensor, will no longer detect the effects of the wing's increased and decreased pressures? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer the question as posed - but I can point you to something related. If you have an (infinite) cylinder perpendicular to a flow, you can calculate the flow around it (see for example [this interesting page](http://www.vermontveterinarycardiology.com/index.php/for-cardiologists/for-cardiologists?id=127) where these images and equations come from).

The velocity profile would look like this:

[image]

and the pressure profile is similar:

[image]

They give the following expression for pressure as a function of distance $r$ and angle $\theta$ (polar coordinates relative to the center of the cylinder):

$$p(r,\theta)=\rho ^2[U^2−(u^2+v^2)]=\frac{\rho U^2}{2}\frac{a^2\left[2r^2\cos(2\theta)−a^2\right]}{r^4}$$

The main takeaway is that large distances, the pressure component drops off with the inverse square of the distance - and with a cosine dependence on angle. So even when you are quite far away you can still feel it.

Now when a wing is finite size, you can imagine that these equations will get an additional factor $r$ in the denominator when the distance is large compared to the wing span - from far away the flow around the wing will look more like flow around a sphere.

Obviously because of the actual shape of the wing you should expect some scaling factors to change, but I expect that in the limit of long distances the above is not too far off. As I said - you need to define your limits of "can't detect".

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. To describe what situation is being modeled, is "perpendicular to the flow" equivalent to the notion of a cylinder moving through a fluid that's at rest (at large distances, obviously fluid around the cylinder is moved), and in zero gravity? Seems like a good start as an approximation, but my physical intuition isn't good enough to give me any sense of how closely this would resemble an airfoil moving through fluid with gravity, in such a way that the lift from the fluid cancels out the downward force from gravity (minus buoyancy).

Comment: IIRC, air flow around a wing, at a distance of several wing chords, is pretty well approximated by the flow around a cylinder plus a circulation. I don't think gravity has a lot to do with it, other than tell us how much circulation you would need to support the weight of the aircraft / wing / cylinder.

Comment: Thanks. One other point is that if Eddie wants a formula in the form I suggested in an earlier comment, we just need a few substitutions: you give pressure as a function of r and theta from the center of the cylinder, if we instead want to imagine the pressure measured by someone standing on a flat surface below the cylinder, at distance R from the point directly below the center and with the cylinder's center at a height h above the plane, then we could substitute r = sqrt(R^2 + h^2), and a little trig shows cos(2theta) = (h^2 - R^2)/(h^2 + R^2).

Comment: plugging those in, if I did the math right the formula for pressure as a function of h and R should be (rho*U^2/2)*a^2*[2(h^2 - R^2) - a^2]/(h^2 + R^2)

Comment: Strictly speaking if you are standing on the ground, the presence of the ground changes the flow (you cannot have a vertical component) so you should add a "mirror source" at equal distance below the earth. This doubles the horizontal components and cancels the vertical components of velocity. Can't do more right now...

Comment: I'm still curious about this one, any chance you could take a look at how the pressure would be modified with the mirror source? Or if you have handy the expression for velocity of the fluid as a function of $r$ and $\theta$ for the moving cylinder, then assuming velocities from two sources obey the superposition principle I could figure out velocities with a mirror source myself, and if there's some simple way to derive pressure from fluid velocity (would [this relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_pressure) be sufficient?) then I could do that on my own as well.

Comment: I think that the rotational component of velocity goes as $1/r$; after that you can just double the horizontal component and cancel the vertical component (at ground level) and finally apply the dynamic pressure equation that you found. This involves lots of approximations but will give you a sense of the magnitude...

Comment: By "rotational component" do you mean that if we describe the velocity vector at each point with $r$ and $\theta$ components, the magnitude of the $\theta$ component decreases as $1/r$? Or something else? If it's that, do you mean I should then estimate the $r$ component of velocity based on the assumption that $v^2$ must be proportional to the pressure function you gave, then translate the velocity vector into x and z coordinates and finally double the x coordinate and cancel the z coordinate to find the velocity at the surface between the cylinder and the image cylinder?

Comment: Flow around air foil (at some distance) is approximated by cylindrical flow plus a rotation. That second part gives rise to the lift (Magnus effect), and follows the $1/r$ relationship. Everything else in your comment sounds sensible.

Comment: Just trying to picture this without a diagram--I gather "cylindrical flow" *without* rotation would look similiar to the B-field around a straight wire, with each velocity vector tangent to a circle in a plane perpendicular to the cylinder's axis? Then would the additional "rotation" for each vector just be a deflection by angle $\theta$? Would the deflection still keep the velocity vector in the plane perpendicular to the cylinder axis? If so would the deflection be outward (like a satellite in circular orbit whose velocity is deflected by a radial force away from Earth) or inward?

Comment: Maybe http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/airplane/map.html will help...

Comment: That's labeled as being the flow for a rotating cylinder, were you assuming the cylinder that in your answer was rotating? And it doesn't illustrate the decomposition of velocity vectors into $r$ and $\theta$ components as you were describing, if it's not just the standard polar coordinate scheme where $\theta=0$ is in the +x direction, and if it's not easy to describe verbally, do you know of any sources with diagrams that do this, online or in textbooks? Without an understanding of the decomposition I wouldn't know how to translate the vectors into x and z components as discussed earlier.

Comment: Yes - rotating cylinder, that is what I meant by "approximated by cylindrical flow plus a rotation". And the horizontal component of cylindrical flow is just $\propto \frac{\cos\theta}{r}$ where $\theta=0$ is straight down. I hope you can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood your comment "Flow around air foil (at some distance) is approximated by cylindrical flow plus a rotation. That second part gives rise to the lift (Magnus effect), and follows the 1/r relationship". I thought you meant that the $\theta$ component was the "second part" besides cylindrical flow, meaning that $\theta$ would somehow measure how each velocity vector deviates from cylindrical flow. But if $\theta=0$ is always straight down then implies $r$ and $\theta$ are just defined in the usual polar coordinate way, and they are just the coordinates of the points that

Comment: (cont) each velocity vector is associated with, they don't describe the direction of the velocity vector itself. The direction of each velocity vector would be determined by the requirement that the magnitude of the vector^2 be proportional to the pressure you gave, and the horizontal component must be proportional to $cos \theta / r$ as you described, so I can calculate the vertical component based on those two requirements. I'll try working on this and see if I can get an equation from it, if so I'll post as another answer.

Comment: Trying to work out the constant of proportionality, something else is confusing me--if the horizontal component of velocity is proportional to $cos \theta / r$ that would seem to imply that when $\theta = \pi/2$ the horizontal component should be zero, and if $\theta = 0$ is straight down then this should be in the horizontal direction away from the cylinder's center. But the page you linked to in your answer includes [this diagram](http://www.vermontveterinarycardiology.com/images/stories/physical/Jowkowski/cylinder-v-vw.jpg) showing nonzero velocity vectors along the horizontal axis.

Comment: The link shows the flow without rotation. There are two components of flow that make up the flow around an airfoil. You need to add them together to get the total flow.

Comment: Got it, thanks. In the case with rotation are there any special angles where the vertical component would be zero, so I could use that to work out the constant or proportionality in the horizontal component, or will I just need to include it as an unknown in the equations?

Comment: Constant of proportionality is determined from the lift you needed - pressure difference between area above and below the plane (velocity above is higher so pressure is lower - which is how you get lift). Depends on mass of plane and area of wing.